# Angular 1.4 compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled returning error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module
>   trainingApp due to: TypeError: $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled is
>   not a function

I'm getting the above error working with Angular 1.4 when opened in the Chrome browser. This issue appears only in Chrome. No issues in Firefox, Edge, IE and Opera. Any ideas?

I checked the angular.js and angular-mocks.js and they are the same version

I was also able to verify that the function does indeed exist in the angular.js file.

Heres the code causing the issue.

```
 .config([    '$compileProvider',
        function ($compileProvider) {
            $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);  //Disabling angular debug data in DOM - production release
            console.log('To debug this application, run this code directly in the console: angular.reloadWithDebugInfo();');
        }])
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using correct version of Angular? Seems really strange. Can you verify which file is loaded in Chrome?

Comment: The file loaded into chrome is "angular.js" version 1.4. I was able to find the debugInfoEnabled function in the browser using Chrome Dev Tools.  The odd part of the issue is the fact that it's specific to Chrome.